# Neo4j Upgrade - https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable

Tags: neo4j, upgrade, centos7, yum

I am trying to upgrade *Neo4j* from repository on my *Centos 7 Server*, but when run `yum update` this is the error:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                   |  32 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * epel: mirror.infonline.de
 * extras: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * updates: mirrors.prometeus.net
base                                                                                                                                                                                   | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                   | 3.2 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable
Trying other mirror.
nodesource                                                                                                                                                                             | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                          | 938 kB  00:00:00     
(2/2): epel/x86_64/primary                                                                                                                                                             | 3.6 MB  00:00:01     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                              12662/12662
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cypher-shell.noarch 0:1.1.4-1 will be updated
---> Package cypher-shell.noarch 0:1.1.5-1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: jre >= 1.8 for package: cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch
---> Package neo4j.noarch 0:3.4.1-1 will be updated
---> Package neo4j.noarch 0:3.4.7-1 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fontconfig(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgif.so.4()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXtst.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXi.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomposite.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.10.95-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fontpackages-filesystem for package: fontconfig-2.10.95-11.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: font(:lang=en) for package: fontconfig-2.10.95-11.el7.x86_64
---> Package giflib.x86_64 0:4.1.6-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libSM.so.6()(64bit) for package: giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libICE.so.6()(64bit) for package: giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.5-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-common >= 1.6.5-1.el7 for package: libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package libXcomposite.x86_64 0:0.4.4-4.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXext.x86_64 0:1.3.3-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXi.x86_64 0:1.7.9-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXrender.x86_64 0:0.9.10-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXtst.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libpng.x86_64 2:1.5.13-7.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mkfontdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mkfontdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.44-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package libICE.x86_64 0:1.0.9-9.el7 will be installed
---> Package libSM.x86_64 0:1.2.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.5-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.12-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.12-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package lyx-fonts.noarch 0:2.2.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package ttmkfdir.x86_64 0:3.0.9-42.el7 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-20.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfontenc.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-20.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXfont.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-20.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXfont.x86_64 0:1.5.2-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libfontenc.x86_64 0:1.1.3-3.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                   Arch                                     Version                                                   Repository                                 Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 cypher-shell                                              noarch                                   1.1.5-1                                                   neo4j                                     2.6 M
 neo4j                                                     noarch                                   3.4.7-1                                                   neo4j                                      84 M
Installing for dependencies:
 fontconfig                                                x86_64                                   2.10.95-11.el7                                            base                                      229 k
 fontpackages-filesystem                                   noarch                                   1.44-8.el7                                                base                                      9.9 k
 giflib                                                    x86_64                                   4.1.6-9.el7                                               base                                       40 k
 java-1.8.0-openjdk                                        x86_64                                   1:1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5                                   updates                                   250 k
 libICE                                                    x86_64                                   1.0.9-9.el7                                               base                                       66 k
 libSM                                                     x86_64                                   1.2.2-2.el7                                               base                                       39 k
 libX11                                                    x86_64                                   1.6.5-1.el7                                               base                                      606 k
 libX11-common                                             noarch                                   1.6.5-1.el7                                               base                                      164 k
 libXau                                                    x86_64                                   1.0.8-2.1.el7                                             base                                       29 k
 libXcomposite                                             x86_64                                   0.4.4-4.1.el7                                             base                                       22 k
 libXext                                                   x86_64                                   1.3.3-3.el7                                               base                                       39 k
 libXfont                                                  x86_64                                   1.5.2-1.el7                                               base                                      152 k
 libXi                                                     x86_64                                   1.7.9-1.el7                                               base                                       40 k
 libXrender                                                x86_64                                   0.9.10-1.el7                                              base                                       26 k
 libXtst                                                   x86_64                                   1.2.3-1.el7                                               base                                       20 k
 libfontenc                                                x86_64                                   1.1.3-3.el7                                               base                                       31 k
 libpng                                                    x86_64                                   2:1.5.13-7.el7_2                                          base                                      213 k
 libxcb                                                    x86_64                                   1.12-1.el7                                                base                                      211 k
 lyx-fonts                                                 noarch                                   2.2.3-1.el7                                               epel                                      159 k
 ttmkfdir                                                  x86_64                                   3.0.9-42.el7                                              base                                       48 k
 xorg-x11-font-utils                                       x86_64                                   1:7.5-20.el7                                              base                                       87 k
 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1                                      noarch                                   7.5-9.el7                                                 base                                      521 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install             ( 22 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  2 Packages

Total size: 90 M
Total download size: 87 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm       FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                                     ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rp FAILED                                          
https://yum.neo4j.org/stable/cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 503 - Service Unavailable                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  neo4j-3.4.7-1.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  cypher-shell-1.1.5-1.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I have followed the Neo4j tutorial for the repo configuration so the installation was successful but when I try to upgrade this is the error.
I can do any upgrade so I think there aren't network problems.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having this issue too on :

wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

HTTP ERROR 503

Update : They are on it

[image]

Update2 : Fixed :) https://debian.neo4j.org

Comment: Thank you so much @Tariq Riahi. Now it's working! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's something on Neo4j's end of things, appropriate people have been notified I think.